# Select box value comes as ID instead of data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, select

I am having a db with 3 tables country , state and city which works fine.

The issue is i am having a form where i can select these three without issues but after selecting and storing the selected value in DB it stores numerical ID instead of the names of these three

**The php part of the select :**

```
<div class="section colm colm6">
<label class="field prepend-icon select">
<select name="country" class="countries" id="countryId">
<option value="">Select Country</option>
</select>
<span class="field-icon"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></span> 
<i class="arrow double"></i>                             
</label>
</div>
```

**JS Part :**

```
    function ajaxCall() {
        this.send = function(data, url, method, success, type) {
          type = type||'json';
          var successRes = function(data) {
              success(data);
          };

          var errorRes = function(e) {
              console.log(e);
              alert("Error found \nError Code: "+e.status+" \nError Message: "+e.statusText);
          };
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: method,
                data: data,
                success: successRes,
                error: errorRes,
                dataType: type,
                timeout: 60000
            });

          }

        }

function locationInfo() {
    var rootUrl = "../api.php";
    var call = new ajaxCall();
    this.getCities = function(id) {
        $(".cities option:gt(0)").remove();
        var url = rootUrl+'?type=getCities&stateId=' + id;
        var method = "post";
        var data = {};
        $('.cities').find("option:eq(0)").html("Please wait..");
        call.send(data, url, method, function(data) {
            $('.cities').find("option:eq(0)").html("Select City");
            if(data.tp == 1){
                $.each(data['result'], function(key, val) {
                    var option = $('<option />');
                    option.attr('value', key).text(val);
                    $('.cities').append(option);
                });
                $(".cities").prop("disabled",false);
            }
            else{
                 alert(data.msg);
            }
        });
    };

    this.getStates = function(id) {
        $(".states option:gt(0)").remove(); 
        $(".cities option:gt(0)").remove(); 
        var url = rootUrl+'?type=getStates&countryId=' + id;
        var method = "post";
        var data = {};
        $('.states').find("option:eq(0)").html("Please wait..");
        call.send(data, url, method, function(data) {
            $('.states').find("option:eq(0)").html("Select State");
            if(data.tp == 1){
                $.each(data['result'], function(key, val) {
                    var option = $('<option />');
                    option.attr('value', key).text(val);
                    $('.states').append(option);
                });
                $(".states").prop("disabled",false);
            }
            else{
                alert(data.msg);
            }
        }); 
    };

    this.getCountries = function() {
        var url = rootUrl+'?type=getCountries';
        var method = "post";
        var data = {};
        $('.countries').find("option:eq(0)").html("Please wait..");
        call.send(data, url, method, function(data) {
            $('.countries').find("option:eq(0)").html("Select Country");
            console.log(data);
            if(data.tp == 1){
                $.each(data['result'], function(key, val) {
                    var option = $('<option />');
                    option.attr('value', key).text(val);
                    $('.countries').append(option);
                });
                $(".countries").prop("disabled",false);
            }
            else{
                alert(data.msg);
            }
        }); 
    };

}

$(function() {
var loc = new locationInfo();
loc.getCountries();
 $(".countries").on("change", function(ev) {
        var countryId = $(this).val();
        if(countryId != ''){
        loc.getStates(countryId);
        }
        else{
            $(".states option:gt(0)").remove();
        }
    });
 $(".states").on("change", function(ev) {
        var stateId = $(this).val();
        if(stateId != ''){
        loc.getCities(stateId);
        }
        else{
            $(".cities option:gt(0)").remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you post example of your json result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the inputs from @piyushanwekar and @HudsonPereira

i made some more changes and made the following code which worked for me finally

```
    function ajaxCall() {
        this.send = function(data, url, method, success, type) {
          type = type||'json';
          var successRes = function(data) {
              success(data);
          }

          var errorRes = function(e) {
              console.log(e);
              //alert("Error found \nError Code: "+e.status+" \nError Message: "+e.statusText);
              //$('#loader').modal('hide');
          }
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: method,
                data: data,
                success: successRes,
                error: errorRes,
                dataType: type,
                timeout: 60000
            });

          }

        }

function locationInfo() {
    var rootUrl = "../api.php";
    var call = new ajaxCall();
    this.getCities = function(id) {
        $(".cities option:gt(0)").remove();
        var url = rootUrl+'?type=getCities&stateId=' + id;
        var method = "post";
        var data = {};
        $('.cities').find("option:eq(0)").html("Please wait..");
        call.send(data, url, method, function(data) {
            $('.cities').find("option:eq(0)").html("Select City");
            if(data.tp == 1){
                $.each(data['result'], function(key, val) {
                    var option = $('<option />');
                    option.attr('value', val).text(val);
                     option.attr('cityid', key);
                    $('.cities').append(option);
                });
                $(".cities").prop("disabled",false);
            }
            else{
                 alert(data.msg);
            }
        });
    };

    this.getStates = function(id) {
        $(".states option:gt(0)").remove(); 
        $(".cities option:gt(0)").remove(); 
        var url = rootUrl+'?type=getStates&countryId=' + id;
        var method = "post";
        var data = {};
        $('.states').find("option:eq(0)").html("Please wait..");
        call.send(data, url, method, function(data) {
            $('.states').find("option:eq(0)").html("Select State");
            if(data.tp == 1){
                $.each(data['result'], function(key, val) {
                    var option = $('<option />');
                        option.attr('value', val).text(val);
                        option.attr('stateid', key);
                    $('.states').append(option);
                });
                $(".states").prop("disabled",false);
            }
            else{
                alert(data.msg);
            }
        }); 
    };

    this.getCountries = function() {
        var url = rootUrl+'?type=getCountries';
        var method = "post";
        var data = {};
        $('.countries').find("option:eq(0)").html("Please wait..");
        call.send(data, url, method, function(data) {
            $('.countries').find("option:eq(0)").html("Select Country");
            console.log(data);
            if(data.tp == 1){
                $.each(data['result'], function(key, val) {
                    var option = $('<option />');
                    option.attr('value', val).text(val);
                     option.attr('countryid', key);
                    $('.countries').append(option);
                });
                $(".countries").prop("disabled",false);
            }
            else{
                alert(data.msg);
            }
        }); 
    };

}

$(function() {
var loc = new locationInfo();
loc.getCountries();
 $(".countries").on("change", function(ev) {
        var countryId = $("option:selected", this).attr('countryid');
        if(countryId != ''){
        loc.getStates(countryId);
        }
        else{
            $(".states option:gt(0)").remove();
        }
    });
 $(".states").on("change", function(ev) {
        var stateId = $("option:selected", this).attr('stateid');
        if(stateId != ''){
        loc.getCities(stateId);
        }
        else{
            $(".cities option:gt(0)").remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the name you should change your option attr line for this one:

```
option.attr('value', val).text(val);
```

Comment: Tried , Still the same mate

Answer (score 1):

What you are using to store in db.?? Above code is just for binding.
Check if you are saving text or value??

The code you provided for binding looks correct.

Comment: I am storing the value , what i want was the value to be the text value instead of id being the value

Comment: `$(this).val()`
returns the value. 

If you want text 
`$(this).text()`

Comment: Yeah I saw that.. but while binding option.attr('value', key).text(val) you are doing like this. Actually what this does , it use the key for value and text for val.

Comment: So either you can replace your code for fetching which will give you text or you can change your code while binding.

Comment: can you kindly guide me with the process on how to do that mate

Comment: var countryId = $(this).val(); replace this with var countryId = $(this).text();

Comment: There is nothing wrong here with your code. Check the jain response that you are getting from server. Also while sending back check what is the json. If possible post it.